# Chaining together promises with a db insert

Tags: node.js, express, es6-promise, bluebird, node-sqlite3

I'm struggling trying to chain together three requests that require synchrony in node.js. Here is my attempt at using promises, but i am getting an error saying that db.run isn't a function. The first action should insert into my sqlite db. The most important thing i need is the
this.lastID variable, which lists the id of the last enetered item. Before attempting to use promises, I was having trouble with scoping. This is important because i need to take this value and use use it in my JSON object under the callback key. Lastly, Im using the requests npm package to send the request.

I am using the bluebird promises library, sqlite3 npm package, nodejs, express.

Any help with this would be awesome because I'm lost.

```
function db() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      db.run(`INSERT INTO scan_requests(name, date) VALUES(?,?);`,  [name,date], function(err) {
         if (err) {
            console.log(err)
         }
         let q = this.lastID
         resolve(q)
     })
   })
 }

db()
   .then(function(q) {
      let options = {
         url: 'API',
         body: {
           name: req.name,
           scan_callback: `http://localhost:80/${q}` 
         },
         json: true
      }
      resolve(options)
   }).then(function(options) {
      console.log(options)
  })
```

Comment: ```return options```? I think you mean ```resolve(options)``` ... no return inside ```Promise``` needed

Comment: @Wainage Yea, im not sure. I'm new to promises. I want to be able to use be able to use that json object in the request below it. How would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

1st rule of "promises" ... always return your "promises". Except when you create a new one.

Try this ...

```
app.post('/route', function (req,res) {
   new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      db.run(`INSERT INTO scan_requests(req.name,req.date) VALUES(?,?);`, [name,date]).then(function(result) {
         let options = {
            url: 'http://API',
            body: {
               name: req.name,
               date: req.date
               callback: `http://localhost:80/${this.lastID}`,
               }, 
             json: true
         }
         // this resolves this promise ... it is now passed on
         resolve(options);
      }).then(function(options) {
         // options is now the result from the promise
         console.log(options)
         request
            .post(options)
            .on('error', function(err) {
               console.log(err)
         })
         .pipe(res)
      });
   });
});
```

**UPDATE** (question modified)

You're using `resolve(options)` but resolve is not in scope there (it doesn't exist). Remember the first rule of promises ...

```
db()
   .then(function(q) {
      let options = {
         url: 'API',
         body: {
           name: req.name,
           scan_callback: `http://localhost:80/${q}` 
         },
         json: true
      }
      // *** change the following line ***
      // --- you must return your data ---
      return options;
   }).then(function(options) {
      console.log(options)
      // -------------------------
      // --- contrived example ---
      // -------------------------
      return { success: true };
  }).then(status => {
      console.log(`Success ${status.success}`);
  });
```

The example includes a rather useless but illustrative example of how to continue passing data down the "promise chain".

Comment: node returns an error saying db.run(...).then is not a function. Any idea?

Comment: Did it run prior to this? I just added the ```resolve``` everything else should be the same

Comment: i updated the question with working code. Where i am struggling now is adding the request call. How can i chain together another .then call and pass my options through?

Comment: ```resolve``` is out of scope where you use it a second time. Check the update to the answer